# Is it possible to limit the access to a Firebase project to a given geographical location?

Tags: firebase

We've developed a Firebase project that is only available to canadian retailers yet we see it is being accessed from all over the world (China, India, Australia etc). We would like to limit access to requests coming from within Canada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to configure.  Firebase services are made to be available wherever someone has an internet connection.

If you must limit access, you need to direct all access through some servers you control that check the IP address of the request and validate that it comes from the nation you would like to restrict to.  This means that you won't be able to use the Firebase client SDKs directly in your client app.